# How to read part of a given file in c

Tags: c, filestream

given file:

**test.txt**

```
ac ab

ad am

av

al

ak aj an az ax

ag ah
```

I want to read from "am to an" or want to start writing to another file when file pointer reaches to **am** and keep writing until file pointer reaches **az**. How can this be done in c.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: You can start by googling "c file tutorial".

Comment: Clarify the question.  Do you want to find instances of the string 'am' in an arbitrary file, or do you want to find the first instance?  Or do you want to seek to a particular location, which in your example file happens to be the location of the string 'am'?  Do you merely want to copy the content between (and including?) the first instance of 'am' until the first (or last?) instance of 'az' into another file?  The short answer to your question is, "with getchar/putchar".

Comment: I wanted to keep copying to a file from a particular location of file until we reach another location of file.

Comment: like say...while i was reading from file in buffer of size=1024, and was comparing it to something and if it got true i'll will have to start coping data from there till buffer complete, again we read from buffer, copy it.It continues .... until we find a desired desired byte/character/condition.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define WORD_SIZE 2

#define _S(x) #x
#define S(x) _S(x)

typedef enum { NO, YES } status;

int main(){
    char word[WORD_SIZE + 1];
    FILE *fin;
    status Processing = NO;
    fin = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    while(1==fscanf(fin, "%" S(WORD_SIZE) "s", word)){
        if(strcmp(word, "am")==0){
            Processing = YES;
        } else if(strcmp(word, "az")==0){
            Processing = NO;
            break;
        }
        if(Processing == YES){
            fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", word);
        }
    }
    fclose(fin);
    return 0;
}
```